# Can't install textract (for python 2.x) on Ubuntu because of pocketsphinx

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have followed the instructions on the textract website, but I am getting an error because of `pocketsphinx`

I have tried installing `pocketsphinx` separtely using `pip` but the same error occurs:

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-drE9wI/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-nfLJNp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-drE9wI/pocketsphinx/

I am trying to install it on Ubuntu 16.04. If it matters, I am running it on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a missing dependency for libpulse-dev  without which the pocketsphinx compilation fails.

Install it as

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
```

In addition, on my Ubuntu, i had to install several other dependencies to get textract working.

```
sudo apt-get install swig
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev libssl-de
sudo easy_install greenlet
sudo easy_install gevent
```