# Issue in Installing textract on Amazon EMR instance (It has CentOS).

Tags: centos

So, when I am trying to install textract in Amazon EMR instance, I am facing this issue. I have tried almost every possible solution on the web, nothing seems to be working for me. Can anyone please help?

> Command - `sudo pip install textract`

```html
Error - 

sleading-indentation
    deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_pulse.c:44:30: fatal error: pulse/pulseaudio.h: No such file or directory
     #include <pulse/pulseaudio.h>
                                  ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-3dsfXm/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lW6lBv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /mnt/tmp/pip-build-3dsfXm/pocketsphinx/
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer - but still might help you.

Faced similar issue - solved by the installation of the following dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev antiword unrtf poppler-utils pstotext tesseract-ocr flac ffmpeg lame libmad0 libsox-fmt-mp3 sox libjpeg-dev libpulse-dev swig
```

**The one missing in textract documentation** is libpulse-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
```

Also solved in the following link:
[Can't install textract (for python 2.x) on Ubuntu because of pocketsphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155508/cant-install-textract-for-python-2-x-on-ubuntu-because-of-pocketsphinx?rq=1)

Comment: Agree ! Its missing

Answer (score 0):

No real answer. At the moment, unfortunately `libpulse-dev` is not supported in Amazon Linux AMI instances.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this myself - leaving answer in case someone else finds in the future and needs it.

```
sudo yum install -y pulseaudio-libs-devel python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel poppler poppler-utils
```

This got me to the point where I could at least extract text from PDFs which was my primary objective.